# /etc/mysql permissions don't let non superuser connect to socket

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

We're running Ubuntu server 13.10 under Vagrant, and have come across an interesting problem.

We're overriding the socket location in conf.d/my.cnf

```
[client]
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /tmp/mysql.sock


[mysqld_safe]
socket                         = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
user                           = mysql
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysql.pid
socket                         = /tmp/mysql.sock
port                           = 3306
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql
bind-address                   = 0.0.0.0
```

So far so good.  Starting up the server, there is in fact a socket listening in /tmp.

However, only the superuser can access it!

As a non superuser, mysql -u root -pXXXX gets the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

The client tries to connect on the wrong socket.

We assumed that the problem was that our non-privileged user can't access the conf files to find the correct socket, and in fact, changing the permissions on /etc/mysql to 0755 fixes this issue, but it doesn't seem like the right fix.

As a side note, on 12.04 this behavior is the same, but is masked by the fact that when mysql starts, it creates the socket at /tmp, but also creates a symlink under /var/run/mysqld, so when the client tries to connect, it finds the default socket.

On both machines, mysql is version 5.5.37.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your exact configuration below might be enough to fix your connection issue.

you can start mysql with --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

from the [Mysql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_socket)

```
--socket=path, -S path
```

> For connections to localhost, the Unix socket file to use, or, on Windows, the name of the named pipe to use.

For having that setting stored without letting the user read the whole mysql config you can change the settings of the ~/.my.cnf file

see [Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) for details

In your case you would add socket=/tmp/mysql.sock to this file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that mysql reads my.cnf in the user's home dir.  That is the solution we're going with.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at a fairly fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and the default permissions on /etc/mysql are 755. To be honest I don't understand why you think that's a problem.